# OpenID Connect for SPAs with backend API - deciding between PKCE vs traditional auth code flow

Tags: authentication, openid-connect

I'm trying to figure out how to implement authentication for an application using [OpenID Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#OpenID_Connect_(OIDC)).

The application's frontend is a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (SPA), written in React. The application has a backend API. The frontend makes APIs calls to the backend API via AJAX in order to retrieve information about the user. This information is a sensitive asset.

In previous companies I've worked with, I've seen two different approaches used to implement OpenID Connect in such scenarios.

- **Approach 1:** Authorization code flow with [PKCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0). The frontend calls the identity provider's `/authorize` and `/token` endpoints, resulting in the frontend gaining possession of an access token. The frontend sends this access token to the backend in future AJAX calls in the HTTP authorization header to prove the user's identity. No client secret is required.
- **Approach 2:** Traditional authorization code flow (without PKCE). This requires us to add an additional backend component: a "helper microservice". This "helper microservice" holds the client secret, and is responsible for making the calls to the identity provider's `/token` endpoint to obtain the ID token and access token. When these tokens are obtained, they get saved as session cookies, so that future AJAX calls made from the browser will carry these tokens in the HTTP cookie header.

Because I don't have in-depth knowledge of browser technology or the potential attack mechanisms by which OpenID Connect systems can be exploited, it is difficult for me to assess the security weaknesses of either approach with confidence. However, certain considerations come to mind.

- **In favour of approach 1.** An obvious advantage with approach 1 is that it is simpler. The mechanism by which the tokens are procured in approach 1 is handled by a standard React component in Auth0's SDK. By contrast, approach 2 introduces a whole new microservice containing *my own* code. This means there is more code to maintain, and therefore, more scope for security flaws due to developer error.
- **In favour of approach 2.** To compromise approach 2, an attacker would have to obtain the client secret, which is held server side and is never sent to the browser. This is difficult for the attacker to achieve. By contrast, in approach 1, the code verifier is held in memory in the browser, and therefore can be exposed to other applications if there is a bug in the browser. Depending on implementation details, there is even a possibility that the code verifier can be leaked by malicious JavaScript libraries imported into *my* application. I don't know enough about browser technology or the implementation of Auth0's React SDK to assess the likelihood of these two scenarios.

I'm also open to the possibility that there are some more fundamental security considerations that I have completely overlooked, as well as the possibility that some part of my reasoning is incorrect due to some misunderstanding on my part.

If it turns out that there is little to separate the two approaches on security grounds, then my preferred tie-break mechanism is to opt for the most *standard* approach. But which approach is most standard? It is hard to tell because there appears to be conflicting information on the internet.

- **Evidence that approach 1 is standard.** Approach 1 is documented in the [Auth0 documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce) as the recommendation for apps with a single-page frontend calling a backend API.
- **Evidence that approach 2 is standard.** [An article](https://curity.io/blog/token-handler-the-single-page-applications-new-bff/) in curity.io appears to describe Approach 2 as the "recommended security option". (See the paragraph about the "Backend for Frontend (BFF)" and the diagram in the section afterwards. Note that in this article, the responsibilities of my "helper microservice" are assumed by the server serving the static HTML/CSS/JavaScript, rather than being carved out into a separate microservice, and frontend requests to the backend API are proxied via this server instead of going directly to the backend API. So the architecture in this article is *not completely* identical to approach number 2.)

So which approach should I choose in order to minimise my application's exposure to compromise?

Comment: Well, ask the question you actually want to ask. Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Note that asking about security aspects of 2 designs is already 2 questions. Re decisions: What is your definition of "better", in enough detail that others would agree on valuations? And then how are you stuck evaluating for yourself? A request for others to decide is generally really a request for a definition & valuation of "best" & generally comes with inadequate detail (since the asker doesn't even know what's relevant) & the true question is for a textbook to be (re)written.

Comment: [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) PS Again: Give what can be given by text via text, don't give images of handwriting, don't leave out text just because an included image augmenting text happens to contain the text, and minimize image text that is redundant there when it should be given as non-image (like your image headings inside the images.) PS Images should also have alt text giving their content in text anyway.

Comment: @philipxy I really appreciate all the feedback you've given. This is so valuable! I've tried to implement as much as of your advice as I can, and I'll keep the rest of your advice in mind  in the future.

Comment: @philipxy Thinking outside the box a little - if you were in my shoes, where would you go to seek help? Fundamentally, I'm looking for an expert to (i) act as a sounding board for my reasoning, (ii) correct my misconceptions, (iii) point out blind spots. This would ultimately result in me making a decision with confidence. I get the sense that Stack Overflow isn't well suited for this. Part of the problem is that - as you've identified - my needs _can't_ be articulated as a single question.

Comment: Well--"looking for an expert"--rent one? SO is not a "sounding board" etc; one metaphor: asking 1 question of a busy colleague at work. (Whose comment & answer tone is ideally as if you were a technically-informed tween child of a sibling of their boss.) There are a lot of Q&A about these issues at meta.SO & meta.SE & no doubt metas of sites related to a topic, see their help & related good Q&As & toleration of vagueness. (Google with 'site:'.) I know you addressed certain meta Q&As at your meta post on this post. The better you research & write your meta Q the more feedback/help you can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PKCE is only a security enhancement to the authorization code flow. So you don't choose one or the other; you either use authorization code flow with PKCE or without.

For modern and new development, I would recommend enabling PKCE to improve the security of your system.

If you need to secure JavaScript applications, then I would suggest looking at the [BFF](https://codemag.com/Article/2203081/A-Deep-Dive-into-the-Back-End-for-Front-End-Pattern) pattern, because dealing with tokens in the browser is never a good idea.

Here are two good videos about BFF:

*[alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw)*

*[Using the BFF pattern to secure SPA and Blazor Applications - Dominick Baier - NDC Oslo 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBFx3MSu1Rc)*

Comment: So you're saying that it makes sense to use PKCE even in Approach 2 (where the tokens are obtained via the back channel)? I didn't think of that.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain why it is not a good idea for the frontend of handle tokens? The way I see it is that if the frontend doesn't handle tokens, then the frontend must handle some other credential that can be exchanged for tokens, which amounts to the same thing. This shows my ignorance. I'll watch the videos now.

Comment: PKCE is a security enhancement to the authorization code flow, as a way to secure the auhtorization code, that is still passed to the client via the browser.

The problem with handling tokens in the browser is that the browser (or mobile apps) are not able to keep secret tokens (like refresh or the access token),, see the videos in my answer for the details.

Comment: Those videos are amazing. I have written up what I've gleaned from those videos as an answer of my own. By all means comment on omissions and misunderstandings. I'm here to learn.

Comment: feel free to accept my answer if it helped you on your yourney!

Answer (score 0):

The [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBFx3MSu1Rc) cited in [Tore Nestenius' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76079936/openid-connect-for-spas-with-backend-api-deciding-between-pkce-vs-traditional/76083812#76083812) go a long way to addressing my needs. For the benefit of future readers who don't have time to watch the videos, I'll summarise the main takeaways that are relevant to my original post. Future readers should bear in mind that this answer is written by somebody who is trying to process information that they have just been exposed to, rather than by an experienced security expert.

**My Approach 1 is standard. My Approach 2 is non-standard - it is similar to a standard approach called backend-for-frontend (BFF), but some of the differences are significant from a security perspective.**

In a BFF architecture, the server that serves the static HTML/CSS/JavaScript content is also responsible for calling the `/token` endpoint on the authorization server to obtain the ID, access and refresh tokens. This server is known as the backend-for-frontend, or BFF. The tokens get saved in encrypted form in a session cookie in the browser. Frontend requests to the resource server API are proxied through the BFF; the session cookies are decrypted in the BFF and the access token is passed on to the resource server. The BFF, being a backend component, is able to store a client secret, which it uses to authenticate with the authorization server. This communication pattern is summarised in the diagram below.

[image: BFF: communication pattern]

BFF is described in the [curity.io article](https://curity.io/blog/token-handler-the-single-page-applications-new-bff/) linked in my original post. It is also the strategy proposed in the two videos linked in Tore Nestenius' answer. BFF is so standard that there is even a company called [Duende](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/bff/) that offers a framework for implementing BFF in ASP.NET applications.

BFF is similar to my Approach 2 in that the `/token` endpoint is called by a *backend* component that holds a *client secret*.

However, a key difference between BFF and my Approach 2 is that the BFF server assumes *three* responsibilities at the same time: (i) it serves the static HTML/CSS/JS content, (ii) it obtains tokens from the authorization server and (iii) it acts as a proxy for requests from the browser to the resource server. (By contrast, the "helper microservice" in my Approach 2 is only responsible for (ii), while (iii) does not happen at all.)

The fact that the BFF simultaneously holds responsibilities (ii) and (iii) is very significant for two reasons.

- It is possible to implement the BFF so that it monitors traffic from the frontend to the resource server, blocking traffic that appears suspicious.
- The tokens can be saved in the session cookie *in encrypted form*. Since all requests from the browser to the resource server are proxied through the BFF, the tokens can be decrypted when they pass through the BFF. Thus the browser *never* handles unencrypted access tokens and refresh tokens. A user cannot inspect the claims inside these tokens by looking inside Dev Tools in the browser, for example.

**[Cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS) is a major attack vector that I failed to consider in my original post. The BFF approach prevents certain kinds of XSS attacks can be carried out under my Approach 1.**

The following are some examples of cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks that an attacker can attempt. I have ranked them in order of likely impact, starting with the most impactful.

- *Attack A.* The attacker injects some JavaScript code which obtains the *refresh token* and sends it to a URL controlled by the attacker. This allows the attacker to access the resource server for long period of time, from the comfort of their own home.
- *Attack B.* Same as attack 1, but the *access token* is exfiltrated instead of the refresh token. This allows the attacker to access the resource server for only the lifetime of the access token.
- *Attack C.* The attacker injects some JavaScript code which makes calls to the resource server to obtain sensitive assets, in the same way that the legitimate JavaScript code makes calls to the resource server, i.e. by Ajax calls. These assets are sent to a URL controlled by the attacker. This is known as *session riding*.
- *Attack D.* The attacker scrapes sensitive information already rendered on the page, and sends this information to a URL controller by the attacker.

So how do our approaches fare against these attacks?

- My Approach 1 protects against attack A, but leaves the door open to attacks B, C and D.
- The BFF approach protects against attacks A and B, partially mitigates against attack C, and leaves the door open to attack D.

Overall, the BFF offers greater protection than Approach 1.

Let me justify these statements.

- Approach 1 protects against attack A if Auth0's React SDK is used. This is because Auth0's React SDK takes care to handle the refresh token only within the context of a working thread. Only the access token is exposed to the global context; the refresh token is not.
- The reason why BFF approach protects against attacks A and B was not fully fleshed out in the videos to my satisfaction. My current understanding is that the tokens are stored in the browser within the session cookie, which is an *HttpOnly* cookie. Therefore, a piece of JavaScript injected by XSS cannot obtain the session cookie simply by accessing `document.cookie`.
- The BFF approach can partially mitigate against attack C by monitoring traffic proxied through the BFF, blocking any traffic that appears suspicious.

**The BFF approach is favoured over my Approach 1 for applications dealing with highly sensitive data. If the data is not highly sensitive, then one may prefer Approach 1 for its simplicity.**

This is the point of view articulated in the [Philippe de Ryck video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw). The [Dominick Baier video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBFx3MSu1Rc) advocates for BFF hands down, but the presenter also acknowledges his biases as a security enthusiast - a certain amount of humour is implicit.

An example of an application where BFF may be preferred for its additional security is an application that processes healthcare data. An example of an application where Approach 1 may be preferred for its simplicity is an application that stores blog articles.

**Protecting against XSS may be a better investment of time than making changes to the choice of OpenID Connect protocol.**

This piece of advice is offered in the Philippe de Ryck video. The advice follows logically from our analysis because (i) all the clear-cut attack vectors that we have outlined are examples of XSS, and (ii) none of the approaches on the table are successful at defending against *all* of the types of XSS that we have outlined.